# How to add a widget by its shortcode on Wordpress posts

Tags: wordpress

Is there any way we can assign a shortcode to already created widget and later use that
shortcode in our specific posts and pages to show that widget instead of trivial method of
showing widgets in sidebar ? I googled about this stuff didn't find anything relative.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't understood your question completely. But as far as what I have understood, may be the below solution help you:

This is the plugin to call widgets on pages/posts:

http://wordpress.org/plugins/widgets-on-pages/

Try the above mentioned plugin. It might help you.

Hope it helps you..!!!

Answer (score 0):

add this function to fucntions.php of your theme

```
  function widget($atts) {
  global $wp_widget_factory;    
  extract(shortcode_atts(array(
      'widget_name' => FALSE
  ), $atts));

  $widget_name = wp_specialchars($widget_name);

  if (!is_a($wp_widget_factory->widgets[$widget_name], 'WP_Widget')):
      $wp_class = 'WP_Widget_'.ucwords(strtolower($class));

      if (!is_a($wp_widget_factory->widgets[$wp_class], 'WP_Widget')):
          return '<p>'.sprintf(__("%s: Widget class not found. Make sure this widget exists and the class name is correct"),'<strong>'.$class.'</strong>').'</p>';
      else:
          $class = $wp_class;
      endif;
  endif;

  ob_start();
  the_widget($widget_name, $instance, array('widget_id'=>'arbitrary-instance-'.$id,
      'before_widget' => '',
      'after_widget' => '',
      'before_title' => '',
      'after_title' => ''
  ));
  $output = ob_get_contents();
  ob_end_clean();
  return $output;

}  
add_shortcode('widget','widget');
```

and use the short code in you post like this

```
[widget widget_name="Your_Custom_Widget"]
```